# Laravel unique validation on update not working by passing id in validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

In my controller i am inserting data in three different table at a time.
I have put validation before inserting in some of the unique fields. But at the time of Update it says email already exists. I have searched a lot and got a solution which is working for everyone except for me by passing id in validation rule.

I have tried

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'admission_no'=>"required|unique:students,admission_no,$id",
    'student_email=>"required|unique:students,student_email,$id",
     'guardian_email'=>"required|unique:student_parents,guardian_email,$id"
]);

$student = Student::find($id);
$student->admission_no = $request->admission_no;
$student->student_email = $request->student_email;
$student->save();
//parent model
$parent = StudentParent::where('student_id',$student->id)->first();
$parent->guardian_email = $request->guardian_email;
$parent->save();
```

It doesn't work this way i dont know why
also the main problem is **StudentParent** model is different how to pass id in validation for this model to unique update

Comment: you have type in:'student_email->"required|unique:students,student_email,$id",
should be:
"student_email"=>required|unique:students,student_email,$id",

Comment: remove id from validation when you inserting new record. use only when you updating info.

Comment: @OMR sorry it was a typo

Comment: @uditrawat i am updating a record

Comment: $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'admission_no' => 'required|unique:students,admission_no,' . $id
]); try like this and also check if $validateData->passes() then update record.

Comment: @uditrawat i have tried this way as well  but didn't work

Comment: @aarushmagar, I answered your question. You need to pass `student_parents` table id on `guardian_email` validation. In this case you need to get that table id before this validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `students` and `student_parents` table has different `$id`, So you need to pass `student_parents` table `id` on `guardian_email` validation :

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'admission_no'=>"required|unique:students, admission_no, $id", // expect students table id
    'student_email'=>"required|unique:students, student_email, $id", // expect students table id
    'guardian_email'=>"required|unique:student_parents, guardian_email, $student_parents_id" // pass student_parents table id here
]);
```

Hope this helps